# Deciphering this syntax error

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I cant seem to understand the reason for these syntax errors. The following is part of my code. I have strict and warnings implemented.

```
my $res = $s->scrape(URI->new($urlToScrape));

#warn Dump $res;
print "Show :".$res->{showtitle}[0];
my @sct;
if ( defined {season}[0] ) {
    print $res->{season}[0];
    @sct=split(' ', $res->{season}[0]);
} else {
    my @spaa=split( {showtitle}[0], {fulltitle}[0] );
    print "Couldnt find season num at proper position\n";
    print $spaa[0]."\n";
    print $spaa[1]."\n";
    exit;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
$ ./htmlscrape.pl
"my" variable @spaa masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./htmlscrape.pl line 43.
"my" variable @spaa masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./htmlscrape.pl line 44.
syntax error at ./htmlscrape.pl line 37, near "}["
syntax error at ./htmlscrape.pl line 40, near "}"
syntax error at ./htmlscrape.pl line 46, near "}"
Execution of ./htmlscrape.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code to be sure, but the syntax error is pretty clear: you've declared `@spaa` somewhere else.

Comment: Shouldn't `defined {season}[0]` be `defined $res->{season}[0]`?

Comment: The same goes for `{showtitle}[0], {fulltitle}[0] `

Comment: Thank you. I missed those. Too little sleep does that sometimes.

Comment: make that an answer, @KeithThompson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's syntax error in your code. Change:

```
if ( defined {season}[0] )
```

to

```
if ( defined $res->{season}[0] )
```

and

```
my @spaa=split( {showtitle}[0], {fulltitle}[0] );
```

to

```
my @spaa=split( $res->{showtitle}[0], $res->{fulltitle}[0] );
```

Also you are getting the warning

`"my" variable @spaa masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./htmlscrape.pl line 43.`

That means you have declared two arrays with the same name `@spaa` in same scope. You'll probably find [Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html) by Dominus worth reading. Pay particular attention to the section called "Lexical Variables".

Comment: The `@spaa` error is a result of the syntax error, for some reason it triggers twice.